Azure Verified Modules in Bicep not resolving modules list in intellisense
I have started to look at Azure Verified Modules using Bicep in Visual Studio Code and I'm experiencing an issue getting Intellisense to resolve the modules list.
Creating a test.bicep file and referencing the br/public alias does not show me a list of published modules as I have seen in a couple of demos.


Full Error Message:

The OCI artifact reference "br:mcr.microsoft.com/bicep/" after resolving alias "public" is not valid. The artifact path segment "bicep/" is not valid. Each artifact name path segment must be a lowercase alphanumeric string optionally separated by a ".", "_" , or "-".

Tools:

Azure CLI Version - 2.60.0
Bicep Version - 0.26.170
Visual Studio Code Version - 1.88.1
Bicep Extension Version - 0.26.170

Any idea why it cannot resolve the artifact reference?
EDIT: It's also worth noting that if I manually complete the module reference it downloads it to the .bicep\br folder.
module nsg 'br/public:avm/res/network/network-security-group:0.1.3' = {
}


Not directly a solution for this question but I had the same error because I was writing resource instead of module before the namespace.
